# How to view overload signatures in Visual Studio 2015's tooltip

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 (and older versions) have a tooltip when you hover over various identifiers that will tell you information like the type and method signatures. A screenshot of this functionality is shown below:

[image]

When there are overloads, as there is below, I'd like some way to be able to view these overloads. I find this is a somewhat common case as I'd like to identify if an overload might have something closer to what I actually need.

When typing the method for the first time, such is possible and the tooltip has arrows that make it clear that you can do this (the up/down arrow keys switch between overloads here):

[image]

I also note that this window has more details, which would be useful to have when hovering. This dialogue isn't so easy to open, however, once the code has already been written (I seem to have to type the method call from scratch).

Is there any way to view the overloads when hovering alone? Or perhaps more ideally, to be able to see the second window when hovering over the identifier?

It doesn't have to be a native feature. A compatible extension would work as well. I'm thinking of C# in particular, but it doesn't have to be just that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Place the insertion point between the () and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Then use the arrow keys to navigate.

[image]